# F# asynchronous sequence calculation gets stuck

Tags: asynchronous, f#

Given the following (simplified) F# asynchronous code, to partition items coming from an asyncSeq

```
open FSharp.Control

let s : AsyncSeq<'t> = ...

let a =  
    s
    |> AsyncSeq.mapi (fun i a -> (i, a))
    |> AsyncSeq.groupBy (fun (i, _) -> int(i) % 3)
    |> AsyncSeq.map (fun (index, tWithIndex) -> (index + 1, tWithIndex |> AsyncSeq.map (fun (_, t) -> t)))
    |> AsyncSeq.toArraySynchronously
    |> Map.ofArray
    |> Map.map (fun i a -> a |> AsyncSeq.toArraySynchronously)

let b =  
    s
    |> AsyncSeq.mapi (fun i a -> (i, a))
    |> AsyncSeq.groupBy (fun (i, _) -> int(i) % 3)
    |> AsyncSeq.map (fun (index, tWithIndex) -> index + 1, AsyncSeq.toArraySynchronously tWithIndex |> Array.map (fun (_, t) -> t))
    |> AsyncSeq.toArraySynchronously
    |> Map.ofArray
```

I was expecting a and b to contain the same Map<int, 't[]> value, but b calculation never completes, it gets stuck.
What's wrong with b's expression?

Comment: It's a deadlock. In `b` you're calling a blocking operation `toArraySynchronously` in the middle of the async flow. The sync operation can't complete until the sequence has finished, but the sequence is waiting at the `map` step for the sync operation to complete.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a somewhat unexpected behaviour because of how `AsyncSeq.groupBy` works. It creates an asynchronous sequence (of groups), each of which contains an evaluated key and another asynchronous sequence of values in the group:

```
AsyncSeq<'TKey * AsyncSeq<'TValue>>
```

The issue is that the nested `AsyncSeq<'TValue>` sequences only get all their values when the outer asynchronous sequence of groups is evalauted to the end. If you demand a value from the nested async sequence, it blocks until the outer one is evaluated.

I can imagine an implementation of `groupBy` where asking for a value in the nested asyn sequence would actually resume the evaluation, but that is clearly not how it is implemented currently.

Aside from doing what you do in the `a` version, you could also just use the `lazy` keyword to delay the evaluation in the `AsyncSeq.map`:

```
let b =  
  s
  |> AsyncSeq.mapi (fun i a -> (i, a))
  |> AsyncSeq.groupBy (fun (i, _) -> int(i) % 3)
  |> AsyncSeq.map (fun (index, tWithIndex) -> 
       index + 1, 
       lazy ( AsyncSeq.toArraySynchronously tWithIndex 
              |> Array.map (fun (_, t) -> t) ))
  |> AsyncSeq.toArraySynchronously
  |> Map.ofArray
```

Comment: Even if `groupBy` produced sequences that didn't wait to the end, it wouldn't matter. The OP's code has to wait to the end just because of `toArraySynchronously`, which has to see the sequence end before it can return an array.

Comment: @FyodorSoikin I think it could work if both the inner and the outer async sequences `groupBy` "pulled more data from the source" whenever the person processing them wanted to get more data (which they reasonably should be able to do) - it would be less lazy, but that can be expected for this kind of operation...

Comment: That would only work if `groupBy` was waiting for the sequence to end before returning the groups.

Comment: I think it could wait for the sequence to end whenever either the inner or the outer sequence is demanded - so it would wait either when someone asks for all the groups or when someone asks for all the elements of any of the group. I still think that should work?

Comment: That's what it's doing right now: waits for the inner sequence to end when it's demanded. The problem is, it's demanded within the sequence itself. That's the whole deadlock.

Comment: So, I wrote a version of `AsyncSeq.groupBy` that explains what I mean - and it does not deadlock in this case: http://fssnip.net/862 (comes with a usual disclaimer - it may have bugs and does not handle errors.)